# Regular Expression accept exactly 4 digit number. Including 0 at beginning

Tags: php, regex

I need to create regular expression that make sure the number the user enter include 4 digit number even if the firsts digits are 0.

- `0001` should be true.
- `00020` should be false.
- `030` should be false.

This regex should contained in a class, and when I use : **/^\d{4}$/** it does not work if the number start with 0. (automatically changed to int and remove the zero..).
If I put the number in "" it works but I want better regular expression for that.

How can I write a Regex in order it accept 0 in the beginning of the number?

Thanks
here is my code:

```
public function set_id($num){   
        $preg = "/^[0-9]{4}$/"; 
        if(preg_match($preg, $num))
            {$this->id = $num;}
            else {echo "<b>ID</b> can not accept less then 4 digit number!";}
    }
    public function get_id(){
        return $this->id;
    }
}

$a = new Business();
$a->set_id(0012);
echo $a->get_id();
```

Comment: Are you doing anything like casting to an integer before validating with this regexp?

Comment: `set_id(0012)` does not differ from `set_id(12)`. Leading zeroes are not preserved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
$number = '49';
$formattedNumber = sprintf('%04d', $number);
echo $formattedNumber;
```

Result:

```
0049
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions work on strings, not numbers. So if the leading zeroes have been removed, that means your input string has already been parsed into a number. You need to stop that from happening - the regex itself is correct and [works just fine with leading zeroes](http://regex101.com/r/iQ2gL5).

Comment: here is my code:
 public function set_id($num){ 
  $preg = "/^[0-9]{4}$/"; 
  if(preg_match($preg, $num))
   {$this->id = $num;} 
   else {echo "<b>ID</b> can not accept less then 4 digit number!";}
 }
 public function get_id(){
  return $this->id;
 }
}

$a = new Business();
$a->set_id(0012);
echo $a->get_id();
......

Comment: You need to call `set_id('0012');`, not `set_id(0012);`.

Answer (score 0):

Because php objects are dimamicly and '123' (String) equal 123(int), My field always changes Unless I use verbumSapienti solution.